# Why was Bruce's silence referred to as a "Walt Disney"?

Tags: dialogue, bruce-almighty

Early on in *Bruce Almighty*, Bruce learns that he's been passed over for promotion in favour of Evan Baxter, and immediately afterwards he has to deliver a report on the *Maid of the Mist* at Niagara Falls. When the anchors hand over to him, he's still staring at the camera in dumbfounded silence, and the director remarks,

> We've got a Walt Disney.

It's fairly obvious that he's referring to Bruce's silence, but **why did he refer to it as a "Walt Disney"?** Is there a reference I'm not getting? i know Walt Disney pioneered sound cartoons, so is it meant to be ironic?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> Is there a reference I'm not getting? i know Walt Disney pioneered sound cartoons, so is it meant to be ironic?

At one point in time, it was rumored that Walt Disney had been cryogenically  frozen upon his death, so that he could be reanimated in the future. This, however, did **not** happen..

In 1972, Bob Nelson, who was at that time the president of the California Cryogenics Society, is quoted saying the following:

> "Walt Disney wanted to be frozen. Lots of people think that he was, and that the body's in cold storage in his basement. The truth is, Walt missed out. He never specified it in writing, and when he died the family didn't go for it. They had him cremated. I personally have seen his ashes. They're in Forest Lawn. Two weeks later we froze the first man. If Disney had been the first it would have made headlines around the world and been a real shot in the arm for cryonics. But that's the way it goes." [source](http://www.lamag.com/askchris/walt-disney-is-still-not-frozen/)

### So, by saying, "we've got a Walt Disney", it's making a joke out of the rumor that Walt Disney was cryogenically frozen after he died.

To provide a bit more dialogue from *Bruce Almighty* which further supports this:

> DIRECTOR: We've got a Walt Disney.
>
> CONSOLE OPERATOR: Frozen solid.

Comment: Oh, of course! The cryogenics rumour! That makes perfect sense! Thanks for explaining it!

Comment: Wow didn't realize the rumor was that close to being true. Thought it was completely fictitious but really it was a clerical error and two weeks difference...

Comment: Best non-checked paranoid theory out there: Disney released Frozen to change Google result's for "Frozen Walt Disney". So good I don't care it isn't true.